# React aliases cant be used with bracket notation accessor

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'd like to use the alias feature in order to build a tabbed-page. JSX doesn't seem to support object bracket-accessors. What could I do? The dot-notation would make the alias obsolete for me.

```
import * as Routes from "./routes"
<Routes[activeTab]/>     //Doesn't work, unexpected token [
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a variable

```
const Route = Routes[activeTab];
<Route />
```

Comment: Yes, that works. I tried that out before because it's obvious. Not it works ... must have changed sth :)